# How can a table be returned from an Oracle function without a custom type or cursor?

Tags: oracle, function, types, cursor

I am looking to return a table of results from an Oracle function.  Using a cursor would be easiest, but the application I have to work this into will not accept a cursor as a return value.  The alternative is to create a type (likely wrapped in a package) to go along with this function.  However, it seems somewhat superfluous to create several types (I have 4+ functions to write) just so I can return table results.  Is there an alternative that I am missing?

Comment: Superfluous? I think that the GROUP BY clause is superfluous if I have an aggregate function in the select list, but hey, it is what it is.

Comment: What kind of application which uses a database doesn't accept cursors???

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** See the first comment for TABLE solution without limit of size.

Return a **VARRAY** or use a **PIPELINED** function to query from them.

- For **VARRAY** look in [this](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/codesnippet/jdbc/varray/index.html) article for a detail. Code example from there:

  ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMPARRAY is VARRAY(20) OF VARCHAR2(30)
   /

   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getEmpArray RETURN EMPARRAY
   AS
     l_data EmpArray := EmpArray();
     CURSOR c_emp IS SELECT ename FROM EMP;
   BEGIN
     FOR emp_rec IN c_emp LOOP
       l_data.extend;
       l_data( l_data.count ) := emp_rec.ename;
     END LOOP;
   RETURN l_data;
  END;
  /
  ```
- For **PiPELINED** functions checkout [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/pl_sql/htdocs/x/Table_Functions_Cursor_Expressions/Pipelined_Table_Functions.htm). Code example:

  ```
   create or replace function Lookups_Fn return lookups_tab
     pipelined
   is
     v_row lookup_row;
   begin
     for j in 1..10
     loop
       v_row :=
         case j
           when 1 then lookup_row ( 1, 'one' )
           --...
           when 7 then lookup_row ( 7, 'seven' )
           else        lookup_row ( j, 'other' )
         end;
       pipe row ( v_row );
     end loop;
     return;
   end Lookups_Fn;
   /

   select * from table ( Lookups_Fn );
  ```

Comment: Why use a VARRAY and restrict to maximum of e.g. 20 results?  Use TABLE: CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMPARRAY is TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30).

Comment: BECAUSE, he said he was trying to AVOID using TYPES. Read the OP

Comment: @Mark Pipelined AVOID tipes, it isn't?

Comment: Not only does a pipelined function require a table-type to pipe, but you're back to returning a cursor which the OP didn't want in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You could always return XML from your function if that suits the application developers.

XML can be generated a number of ways in Oracle, depending on what you have installed and what version you're using.

XMLTYPE is very useful in certain contexts, and can be generated from SQL using the XMLElement, XMLAttributes, XMLAgg, etc. built-in functions.  If the client doesn't support XMLTYPE it can easily be cast to CLOB values.

Perhaps the simplest, though not the best (IMO) option is to use the dbms_xmlgen package:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on size 1000;
SQL> exec dbms_output.put_line( dbms_xmlgen.getXML( 'select * from dual' ) );
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <DUMMY>X</DUMMY>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

That gives you your "table" results in a single CLOB value.